# SharePoint 2013 restrict access for specific user on a specific document

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2013

I have a document library and it is shared with a group which contains some users.

In this library i want to restrict specific user in the group from accessing a specific document.

Is this doable in SharePoint 2013?

thanks,

Comment: How about asking here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: You must break role inheritance for the specific document, remove the group and add only the user you want. To be clear: you cannot add on Sharepoint denial permission.